# No Solution scaffolding or files added after adding MVVM Light

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

I am trying to add `MVVMLight` to a `Xamarin Forms` app. The previous app in which I added `MVVMLight` it did some scaffolding and added `BaseViewModel`,`ViewModelLocator` etc. which is not visible when I am adding it now. I have also tried adding MVVMLight

I am using `Xamarin Forms Version="3.0.0.482510"` ,`MVVMLight V5.4.1`
Can someone help ?